# Your project have installed babylon version null but Android platform requires version ^6.4.5

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

When I run: `tns platform add android` this error occours:

`➜   tns platform add android

Copying template files...
Your project have installed babylon version null but Android platform requires version ^6.4.5.`

I already try `install npm install babylon` and `rm -rf node_modules platforms` but this doesn't works

Comment: Are you using Angular? Is it a new project from the default template?  May I know the version of your nativescript-angular & CLI version?

Comment: Yes, I'm using angular. It is from my personal project created with default template. 

"nativescript-angular": "^6.0.0",
tns --version - 4.2.1

Comment: Did you try upgrading to latest CLI? Between may I also know your NodeJS version? Are you a windows user?